# MVC controller returned parameter as null for complex data type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public class FileSubmissionModel
{
    public List<DraftFile> ValidFiles{ get ; set ;  }
    public List<DraftFile> InvalidFiles{ get ; set ;  }
}
```

Where:

```
public class DraftFile
{

    public Guid DraftId { get ; set ;  }
    public string OriginalFileName { get ; set ;  }
}
```

Gives a null on:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2(FileSubmissionModel validFiles)
{
 ...
}
```

The parameter 'validFiles.ValidFiles' & 'validFiles.InvalidFiles' are returned as null. Does anyone know why and what I can do to correct this?
Cheers,
Pete

View code as asked for...I've snipped some out but you get the gist:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.InvalidFiles)
        {
        count++;
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InvalidFiles[count].DraftId) 
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InvalidFiles[count].OriginalFileName ) 
        </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: @PeterG can u show ur view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the parameter to the Step2 method **validFiles** is the same as the **ValidFiles** property on the *FileSubmissionModel*.

Assuming that within the view you are doing something like:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 <p>  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValidFiles[i].DraftId)</p>
}
```

The name of the field will be generated as **ValidFiles[0].DraftId** which is what gets posted back to the server.

The default model binder is trying to bind to the parameter rather than to the property on the model because the names are the same and the default model binder does a case insensitive match.

My advice right now is to change the name of the parameter on your method.

Comment: Ah! I can't believe it - what a simple fix, how stooopid am I! Thanks for that, sometimes the MVC 'magic sauce' really throws me.